# Vuejs: How to bind a variable to global css class?

Tags: css, vuejs2

I would like to bind a variable as it:

```
<style lang='sass'>  
  .picker-item.picker-item-selected
    background-color: {{ MY_BG_COLOR }}
</style>
```

this obviously does not work.

For the context I'm using a [picker from framework7](http://framework7.io/docs/picker.html) which I want to override the `background-color` depending of user actions.

Then I cannot really use [usual ways to bind values for styling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Is there a way to bind a value for global css class?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that you want directly, but you can **Use "inline style"**:

You must to bind an inline style with a variable

```
<div id="app">
  <div :style="divInline">Hello</div>
</div>
```

You must create the variable in the data section

```
data: {
  divInline: 'background-color:red;'
}
```

after that, you can change the inline style through methods.

```
methods: {
  changeColor( color ) {
    this.divInline = 'background-color:' + color + ';'
  }
}
```

[Example complete](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MBPMjL)

Comment: because the class is inside a framework7 component I cannot do this way